# If a self mapping linear functional is a projection, is it reducible?

Tags: linear-algebra

$V$ is a vector space and $T\in L(V,V)$.

If $T$ is a projection then is $T$ reducible?
If $T$ is reducible then is $T$ a projection?

I am not sure if the first question is true since I am unsure of the case where $V$ is infinite dimensional and I have no way to show the second question is true.

Comment: What does "reducible" mean???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich We say that $T \in L(U,U)$ is reducible if there are nontrivial
invariant subspaces $V,W$ of $T$ so that $U = V \oplus W$.

Answer (score 2):

The first assertion is true unless $T$ is either trivial or the identity map.

Since $T^2 = T$, for every $v \in V, T(Tv) = Tv$, so $\operatorname{im} T = T(V)$ is invariant under $T$, and $T(v - Tv) = 0$, so $v - Tv \in \ker T$. $\ker T \cap \operatorname{im} T = 0$ so $V = \operatorname{im} T\oplus \ker T$. $\ker T$ is invariant under $T$, so as long as neither $\operatorname{im} T$ nor $\ker T$ is trivial, $T$ must be reducible. $\operatorname{im} T$ being trivial means $T \equiv 0$. And $\ker T$ being trivial means that $v - Tv = 0$ for all $v$, making $T$ the identity map.

Note that this applies without any regard to the dimension of $V$.

For your second assertion, consider $$T = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$$